# How to get first element from a Room DB flow?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, coroutine

I have a function like so in my Repository

```
fun getSelfReportMetaById(cardId: String): Flow<SelfReportMeta?> {
        return selfReportMetaDao.getById(cardId)
                .map { it.map { entity -> entity.toSelfReportMeta() } }
                .map {
                    it.firstOrNull()
                }
    }
```

The idea is to get a unique field out of my database. I do not expect multiple elements per cardId.

In my viewModel, I want to check the DB to see if the key already exists. If it does not exist, we will create a new one. If it exists, we will take it, update it, and insert it back into the database.

```
userRepository.getSelfReportMetaById(cardId)
                    .onEach { userCard ->
                        if (userCard == null) {
                            userRepository.insertSelfReportMeta(createNewSelfReportMeta(cardId))
                        } else {
                            userRepository.insertSelfReportMeta(updateSelfReportMeta(userCard))
                        }
                    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

What's the issue? The issue is that when this function runs, the else{} block will run basically continuously until I go to the next view. I know this because updateSelfReportMeta() has an increment operation (++), and the integer value continuously goes up. I just want it to happen once.

Comment: Instead of returning a Flow of a nullable value, you can consider having `suspend fun getSelfReportMetaById(cardId: String): SelfReportMeta?` returning a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [suspending function `first`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html) to take the first value emitted by the flow and then terminate the flow.

Your code would change to something like

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val userCard = userRepository.getSelfReportMetaById(cardId).first()
    if (userCard == null) {
        userRepository.insertSelfReportMeta(createNewSelfReportMeta(cardId))
    } else {
        userRepository.insertSelfReportMeta(updateSelfReportMeta(userCard))
    }
}
```